# An interactive, animated deliverable (i.e. in PDF)? How?

Tags: software-recommendations, pdf, animation

I'm wondering if it's possible to make something like this:

http://tipstrategies.com/geography-of-jobs/

But in the form of a deliverable? Like a PDF? I'd like to make something similar that I could email to people.
If yes, what skills/resources are needed to accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the time manager plugin to create your animation then export in video format or image series ( depending on your OS the procedure may be different) that you convert in animated gif. (https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/blob/master/README.md)

This is not interactive but i think that's the only way if you want to send it by Email to people that may not have specific software to read more interactive format

If you want to use pdf you may explore the option to create layered pdf (where you can turn on and off the different layer and include feature attributes), it's still not really interactive and these fonctionnality are not known of everybody who may receive your pdf